# How to print the first letter in a string in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am having my user input their name and then I will be giving them their initials, but I am having trouble printing the first letter of each string. I think something like this:

```
    seperated[1]
```

Only works to print the first letter if its in a string, but when I do it in a list, it just prints the first item. How do I tell it to print the first letter of the first string in the list?

```
name = str(input('Enter a name: '))
separated = name.split(' ')
```

Comment: `seperated[1]` does not print the first letter of string and first item in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution:

```
first = separated[0]
second = separated[1]
third = separated[2]
```

and then I printed the first letter of each string.

Answer (score 2):

You are Splitting the name on the basis of ' ' so it will only spilts the name

like you have enter the name (rohit kumar)

so it will just split the the first and last name and not give you the initials of the name

Comment: I did that on purpose in order to separate the name. Should I have done it another way?

Comment: What you want as output ? just the initials of the name or full names ?

Comment: Just initials of the name

Comment: And after splitting names as you did fetech the first character that is at index 0

Answer (score 1):

You should look into pythons `slicing` options 
https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

`name[:1]`

to print the first character of each word:

```
for word in separated:
   print(word[:1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You know how to access an item in an array with `separated[0]`, but strings are also technically arrays of characters! So you can access the first letter of the first string in the array with `separated[0][0]`.
Also, `str.split()` splits using whitespace by default (so defining ' ' as a separator isn't required), and to get the initials from the resulting array:

```
name = 'Jane Doe'  # User input
separated = name.split()  # ['Jane', 'Doe']
first_initial =  separated[0][0]  # 'J'  
last_initial = separated[1][0]  # 'D'

print(f'Your initials are: {first_initial}.{last_initial}.')
```

Here's some relevant resources for you:

[str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html)

[python's f-string syntax](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

and @Alex included a link above about slicing strings/arrays/tuples

Answer (score 0):

```
name = str(input('Enter a name: '))
x = name.split(' ')

print(x[0][0])
print(x[1][0])
print(x[2][0])
```